# CSS modules show random letters instead of className

Tags: css, css-modules

The styles are applying correctly but I see the below when I inspect an element. Is there a configuration I need to do?

```
<span class="UNKMAiOY4lYdzPcrmll49">BN</span>
```

Comment: Could you add details about what languages are you using? Is it pure html with css? Or does java, rails or anything else gets involved? Are you using frameworks? Can you post an example we can execute?

Comment: If you are using webpack then you need to configure `localIdentName`, here is how it may look: `localIdentName: '[path][name]__[local]--[hash:base64:5]',` and yours probably consist of only `hash` part?